# Remove Only rows that start with a given string in r

Tags: regex, r, subset

I need to remove all rows that start with a given string in a column.  In this example removing all rows that start with example2. in Landing column

I have a data set EX:

```
my.data

BABY      MOM      LANDING
mark      dina    example1.bo
tom       becky   example2.do
brad      tina    example1.eo
mark      dina    example1.ro
bob       kindra  example2.ao
brad      tina    example1.c3po
```

I want my new data to be:

```
new.data

BABY      MOM      LANDING
mark      dina    example1.bo
brad      tina    example1.eo
mark      dina    example1.ro
brad      tina    example1.c3po
```

How do I tell R to remove all rows where my.data$LANDING starts with 'example2.'

Here is my code

```
indx1 <- grepl('^community.', ga.data$pagePath)

ga.data[!indx1, ]
```

but I still have items in the pagePath column that are community.xxxx.com/

Not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: Can you try `grepl('^community\\.', ga.data$pagePath)`

Comment: I see a 12 instances of true statement.  but no change in data set.

Comment: If you are getting 12 TRUE statements and want to remove those rows `ga.data[!grepl('^community\\.', ga.data$pagePath),]` should remove it

Comment: agree with the should, but when I run that, I still end @ the same 1257 obs I started @

Comment: That is strange.  Have you assigned it to a new object? i.e. `ga.data1 <- ga.data[!grepl.....`  Check the `nrow(ga.data1)` or `str(ga.data1)`.  The rownames remains the same unless we change it to NULL.

Comment: That worked!  thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `grep` to get the numeric index of elements that start with 'example2' from the 'LANDING' column and remove that rows from the 'my.data'

```
my.data[-grep('^example2', my.data$LANDING),]
# BABY  MOM       LANDING
#1 mark dina   example1.bo
#3 brad tina   example1.eo
#4 mark dina   example1.ro
#6 brad tina example1.c3po
```

#### data

```
my.data <- structure(list(BABY = c("mark", "tom", "brad", "mark", "bob", 
"brad"), MOM = c("dina", "becky", "tina", "dina", "kindra", "tina"
), LANDING = c("example1.bo", "example2.do", "example1.eo",
"example1.ro", 
"example2.ao", "example1.c3po")), .Names = c("BABY", "MOM", "LANDING"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: after a more precise glance our solutions are slightly different. I used `grel` and and then subset the data with the `!` operator.

Comment: @SabDeM Yes, it is different and you are within the 1 minute legally allowed time for posting :-)

Comment: @rawr it is not necessary. I will loose.

Comment: I gave both answers a shot, to no success,  as a result I updated my question to be more specific.  I am dealing here with Google analytics data I have imported - if that helps?

Comment: @AllyKat I updated with the `my.data` I used.  Can you check if that works or not.  I used `dput` to get that output.  If not, can you update with the dput output.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `grepl` to create a logical index and then subset, with the `!` operator.

```
 ind <- grepl("^example2", df$LANDING)

 df[!ind, ]
  BABY  MOM       LANDING
1 mark dina   example1.bo
3 brad tina   example1.eo
4 mark dina   example1.ro
6 brad tina example1.c3po
```

Comment: Ok so I tried this, I added my code into the question as I still had instances of the issue I am trying to over come.